# Position an image inside of a View

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have a profile image in my header component and the source of it comes from database as a string array. What my problem is when i fetch user picture from database, it is slightly cutted from the top. So the head of user use looks like cutted. The image is in a view with `borderRadius` in order to make it circular.

What i tried:

```
resizeMode: 'cover',
resizeMode: 'contain',
position:'absolute',
bottom: 0,
```

and none of them are worked so far.

If you help me i will be appreciated,
thanks.

PS: i have looked several(more than 10) topics in stackoverflow and i could not make it.

**Update**

Here is my `Header` Component:

```
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.backButtonContainer} >
                    {isBackButtonIconVisible ? this._renderBackButtonIcon() : null}
                </View>
                <View style={styles.textContainer} >
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.profileButtonContainer}>
                    {isProfileIconVisible ? this._renderProfileIcon() : null}
                    {isProfilePictureVisible ? this._renderProfilePicture() : null}
                </View>
            </View>
```

Rendering Profile Picture:

```
    _renderProfilePicture() {
        let profileIcon = (
            <View style={styles.profileButtonContainer} >
                <CircularProfilePicture
                    onPress={this.props.onProfilePress}
                    ProfilePictureSourceUri={this.props.ProfilePictureSourceUri}
                ></CircularProfilePicture>
            </View>
        );
        return profileIcon;
    }
```

Here is my `CircularProfilePicture` component

```
class CircularProfilePicture extends Component {
    render() {
        const {onPress} = this.props;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => onPress()}
                >
                    <Image source={{ uri: 'data:image/png;base64,' + this.props.ProfilePictureSourceUri }}
                        style={styles.image} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 10,        
    },
    image:{
        width: 55,
        height: 60,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        resizeMode: 'cover',
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you used width: 100%; and height: 100%; ? Maybe you could come with a working example of your problem?

Comment: Please provide at least a reproducible example with code, it's really hard to help just by guessing :)

Comment: I have updated my post you can check it again.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
padding:3px; // putting your image in the middle of div, setting in px the  
              value you need 
position:absolute;
width: 200px;    // the value that  you have designed your div
height: 200px;   //the value that  you have designed your div
border-radius:30%;  // set the value you need;
-moz-border-radius: 30%;  //ancient mozzila versions
-webkit-border-radius:30%; //ancient chrome or Safari versions
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have tried what you said but it didnt worked. Btw, my question is for React Native app not for web app maybe this is why your answer didnt worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I think the style props [alignItems](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#alignitems) and [justifyContent](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#justifycontent) might help you center the `Image` inside the `View`. Either that or position the `View` absolute and use `flex: 1` on the `Image` to make it take upp all available space in the `View`.